# Compare two tab's headers, copy column below maintaining blank columns

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I have two tabs, one with all of my column headers (data tab), the other tab with less headers, but all from the data tab.

I want to search the headers of the "data" tab using the headers from the second tab ***starting at column I through BI***. The second tab's headers will periodically change but always be present in the data tab.  If the search criteria isn't present, I want to leave that column blank.  If it is present, return the values below from the data tab.

I've tried a few formulas, but can't quite get what I'm looking for.

This formula worked to find the data:

'FILTERED'!I2

```excel
=FILTER(data!I2:AK,COUNTIFS($I$1:$1,data!I1:AK1))
```

This formula got the placement right, but produced the wrong information:

'Copy of FILTERED'!I3

```excel
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(I2:2),,FILTER(data!I2:AK,COUNTIFS($I$1:$1,data!I1:AK1))))
```

Here's [my sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ym_zbkHhfzLZqNwzf2w4E7FNThTohumgopQwlrElVII/edit#gid=1799840014)

Comment: you said in your post, "If the search criteria isn't present, I want to leave that column blank." What do you intend to do with/in those blank columns? Before I offer a solution, I want to make sure that you know that if you fill the grid in the destination source using a formula, you then CAN'T manually enter anything into those cells in the destination sheet. For instance, right now, you don't have anything in the 'data' sheet for header 'Strength'; so if one formula is going to fill Column I over in the destination, you won't be able fill 'Strength' by other formula or manually.

Comment: Thank you for offering assistance, Erik!  The second sheet is just a helper sheet to maintain column placement.  The actual changes to the data take place on the data tab.  Sometimes when data is download, it doesn't download every column.  Hence the need to identify the column header's presence to populate the appropriate column in the second tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a large range to process, so there may be a slight delay filling the grid by formula (2 or 3 seconds maybe). But I have added a sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula in I2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A2:A),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROW(data!A2:A),{ROW(data!A2:A),INDIRECT("data!I2:"&ROWS(data!A:A))},HLOOKUP(FILTER(I1:1,I1:1<>""),{data!I1:1;SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(data!I1:1),2)},2,FALSE),FALSE))))`

Honestly, it's hard to explain how this works, but I'll try to cover the basics.

`=ArrayFormula(...)`

This just means the formula will be processing a range rather than one cell.

`IF(ROW(A2:A), ... HLOOKUP(FILTER(I1:1,I1:1<>""),{data!I1:1;SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(data!I1:1),2)},2,FALSE) ...)`

`IF(ROW(A2:A)` is important, because it signals to do something for every row, thereby creating a 2D grid instead of just processing the current row. The `HLOOKUP` will look up every header in `I1:1` that isn't blank [`FILTER(I1:1,I1:1<>"")`], which as the sheet is now, will be all of them. They will be looked up in in a virtual array formed from a top row consisting of all headers in `data!I1:1` over a bottom row made up of a SEQUENCE of numbers made of 1 row and the same number of columns as are in `data!I1:1`, starting at the number 2 and moving up. (It starts at 2, because part of the VLOOKUP virtual array which I haven't explained yet, will be forming a column 1.)

`VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A),{ROW(data!A2:A),INDIRECT("data!I2:"&ROWS(data!A:A))}, *the HLOOKUP RESULT NUMBER*,FALSE)`

Now a VLOOKUP will kick in. It will look up every row in `data!A2:A` within a virtual array made of two columns; the first column will be those same row numbers, and the second will be everything from `data!I2` over and down (the `INDIRECT` setup allows this to be a dynamic grid in case you add or delete columns later). As to which column from that should be returns, that will pull from the HLOOKUP results explained above (which, as you'll recall, will all match the headers).

Finally, `IFERROR(...)` will return *null* if any step in that process returns an error, which would be because something wasn't found.

Comment: Thank you very much, Erik!  Works great! But you're right, there is entirely too much data to process quickly.

Comment: Hi Erik! Thank you again for this formula.  As I use the data produced, I noticed that it's out of it's original order, or not associated with the appropriate characters rather. I've tried making various adjustments, but I'm afraid it's out of my scope.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean (regarding the "data produced" being "it's out of it's original order, or not associated with the appropriate characters." If you'd like to be more specific (exact cell/range as example, what it says now, and what you were expecting), I'll try to take another look. But it was producing exactly your "What it should look like" results when I initially set it up, which causes me to wonder if you tried editing my formula and just don't know how to do that properly.

Comment: I just looked at the sheet again, and my results are exactly your results. So again, I'm thinking that you've copied and pasted my formula to another sheet and don't know how to make changes to it in your other sheet.

Answer (score 0):

see:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), {ROW(A2:A), 
 A2:C}, 
 MATCH(HLOOKUP(E1:G1, 
 {E1, F1, G1; 
  B1, A1, C1}, 
 2, 0), A1:C1, 0)
 +1,
 0), 
 "select *"))
```

[image]

for missing headers:

[image]

Comment: Hey player0, thank you for looking at this formula for me.  I tried your formula, but it didn't seem to work for me (something I'm doing wrong, I'm sure).  I made some edits to the sheet that might clear up my goal, if you have time to take another look.